# One-time setup for surefire across multiple unit test maven modules

Tags: java, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a maven project with multiple modules and submodules. Each of these modules and submodule runs several unit tests of their own. As we know, maven-surefire-plugin runs unit tests for each module separately in a new JVM.

Now, as it would often occur, I have some global configuration/setup I need to perform before running tests. This configuration/setup applies to almost all the unit tests across the modules (that means across multiple JVMs). By default, this setup now runs every time, that is, for each (sub)module. If this configuration is a little expensive, it adds a lot to the exceution time.

One such example may be setting up db (clean the db and set it up). If I have 100 modules, this setup would run 100 times.

Is their any good/elegant way of splitting such configuration so it only runs once for the whole project? Also, I do not want to send in any properties through the maven command with -D, and this is make this process completely command-independent.

Comment: Cleaning the DB and setting it up shall not relate to a JVM and could you project how your modules' unit tests are executed such that all of them run in different JVM? Why can you not make use of a BOM/parent POM in such a case?

Comment: DB setup is just an example. I am not sure what you mean by organizing using parent POM. Can you give an example?

Comment: an example of BOM would be `spring`, they use a similar structure to maintain the configurations throughout. a simple search for it shall take you to their implementation.